# Change TFS Process Template Default Workflow States For A WIT

Tags: templates, tfs, configuration, agile, agile-processes

Trying to implement a custom workflow for a bug WIT in the scrum template (Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013.4).

In our business process there is no need for 'committed' and 'approved.'  In fact we could recycle these to represent some other states called 'Ready for Test' and 'Test in Progress,' besides adding a number of new states.

When I change the existing 'committed' and/or 'approved' states (using TFS>Tools>Process Editor>Work Item Types>Open WIT From Server) I get an error message after saving it and reopening the backlog using via the webpage:

```
TF400917: The current configuration is not valid for this feature. This feature cannot be used until you correct the configuration.

Learn about how to correct your configuration

Details about the validation error appear below:

The following element contains an error: BugWorkItems/BugWorkItems. TF400506: This element defines the states for work items that represent Bugs or Defects. Each state must exist in at least one of the work item types that are defined in: BugWorkItems. The following states do not exist in any of the work item types: Committed.
```

What is the 'configuration' mentioned in the error message?! At first I thought it may be the kanban board somehow wired to these existing states but I don't know where to look (or if it is even that)?

I don't want to create a massive template from scratch but rather hack an existing one.  Any advice please?

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudiouk/archive/2013/01/19/adding-additional-states-onto-the-agile-task-board-in-tfs2012.aspx
http://www.datazx.cn/Forums/en-US/2041fa34-0463-4dbc-8fa9-a22012784a9b/action?threadDisplayName=using-bug-work-items-on-task-board

Run admin cmd prompt

Get to the process file
cd %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE>witadmin exportprocessconfig /collection:http://tfs:8080/tfs/sandbox /p:"Sandbox" /f:c:\myConfig.xml

Upload process file after edits within the xml renaming the states
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE>witadmin importprocessconfig /collection:http://tfs:8080/tfs/sandbox /p:"Sandbox" /f:c:\myConfig.xml